# Getting Invalid Value when changing a bound picture edit's image to new image

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a bound picture edit which displays an image of a product from the inventory. I would like to enable the user to select a new image for this product.

The problem that I experience is the Invalid Value once the image is changed and therefore I cannot save the new picture into my database.

Comment: Can you show code and exact error message?

Comment: Is your pictureedit control bind with the some binding source?? If yes then it may be possible you are saving data in database in another format while control using another format... Provide more information with problematic code to understand the issue.